# ALM Synchronizer Adapter Get Endpoint Parameters

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center

When developing an Adapter for HP ALM Synchronizer, in our Adapter class we define method

```
public Map<String, String> getEndpointParams(EntityType entityType)
```

which tells the Synchronizer which are the extra parameters that our Adapter needs.

I would like to know how can I get the values the user filled. If I call the method above, will I get the map with all keys but no values? or will I get the values the user used? Or is there any other method for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **RecordManager** interface is the one that has the method `getEndpointParams()`. So once you create your instance of RecordManager (example: XmlDefectManager) you can call `getEndpointParams()`. 
Additionally, this interface provides 2 method you have to implement:

- `checkEndpointParams(Map<String, String> params)`: here you can check that the parameters provided by the user are valid.
- `setEndpointParams(Map<String, String> params)`: here you set endpoint params to a local variable.